# Google Apps Script Trigger firing randomly

Tags: google-apps-script

I run in this issue where my Google Apps Script trigger has triggered 4 times in a row in a span of 2 minutes, where it is supposed to run every 30 minutes.
The trigger works as intended before those random calls as well as after those random calls. No other triggers running on my account.

I load the trigger like this:

```
function addEveryHalfHourTrigger() {
  Logger.log('Adding a trigger every 30 minutes on getAllClicks()');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('ClickFetcher.getAllClicks')
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(30)
    .create();
}
```

And then I choose it from the UI like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Isha Tools')
      .addItem('Get a Bitlink', 'getBitlink')
      .addItem('Get All Clicks once', 'getAllClicks')
      .addItem('Start the clock trigger', 'addEveryHalfHourTrigger')
      .addToUi();
}
```

I have created the trigger 24h from now, it triggers properly every 30 minutes since then.

Do you know why it has run randomly 3 times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate emails sent from Apps Script project that has a weekly time-based trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263314/duplicate-emails-sent-from-apps-script-project-that-has-a-weekly-time-based-trig)

Comment: The above is an automated message sent on our behalf when we flag the question to be linked to another one that already has an answer to it. Unfortunately, this seems to be an ongoing issue - triggers fire accidentally sometimes. Common workaround is to save current time when the trigger is created and on each run check if the time is correct (i.e. 29 mins in or 31 appx - to give it a margin of error) and update the time on success