# The GAS program is executed multiple times on a single time-based trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I want to execute a function once a minute.

So I used GAS's time-based trigger feature to set the trigger.
However, after that, it was confirmed that the target function was executed more than once within 1 minute.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate emails sent from Apps Script project that has a weekly time-based trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263314/duplicate-emails-sent-from-apps-script-project-that-has-a-weekly-time-based-trig).This seems to be a known issue with time-driven triggers. A workaround would be to create a guard checking if the current time is within "1 minute since the last time trigger fired". That won't stop the trigger, but at least you will only lose a 0.1-0.5 seconds of quota (runtime per day) and won't duplicate whatever the rest of the script is doing

Comment: You might wish to consider a trigger based up client side javascript setinterval function. But of course that requires that you have a computer running to maintain the client.

Answer (score 0):

As @Oleg Valter points out, there is a known issue with time driven triggers, firing multiple times, so the proposed workaround until the issue is fixed, is to store the trigger's "last execution time" as a script property, and in your triggered function add a check to exit the function if the "last execution time" was less than 60 seconds ago.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62264863/4243927) explains the workaround very well.