# App Script Time Based Trigger Executed multiple times

Tags: google-apps-script

We are encountering an issue with google app script, we have a time-based trigger that is set to run daily at 9 PM and it has been running properly daily for a few weeks already between 9 PM and 10 PM.

[image: time-based trigger]

But it has started to run multiple times at the same time on 2 consecutive days now.

[image: Execution Logs]

the `functionTrigger` calls the consecutive triggers but they all should execute only once.

```js
function functionTrigger() {

  try{
    deleteSheets();
  }
  catch(err){
    Logger.log('ERROR DELETE SHEETS');
    Logger.log(err);
  }

  try {
    resetAllDates();
  } catch(err){
    Logger.log('ERROR Reset');
    Logger.log(err);
  }

  try{
    sortGoogleSheets();
  }
  catch(err){
    Logger.log('ERROR SORT SHEETS');
    Logger.log(err);
  }


  ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateFullProducts")
  .timeBased()
  .at(new Date())
  .create();
}
```

this is how it should look like
[image: Correct Execution Logs]

Comment: also created a bug in https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/159238029

Comment: This is a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/157080185) already reported. Please refer to this answer for a workaround solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62264863/7453656